# Problem with Python modules import on Mac

Tags: python, macos, pip, python-module

I've tried tried to install several modules for Python with "*pip install <module_name>*" command. But I still cannot get how it works. I'am able to use only ***pygame*** module, which has been installed with **sudo easy_install** ("pip install" didn't work). Then I've tried to install another, Eel module and I have got strange results. The Eel module is shown in the Terminal list [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmYou.png) (I'm working on the latest Catalina) but python (in Pycharm IDE) **can't read eel** as installed module [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWYiW.png).

I suppose, it's sort of problem with python or pip versions (but pypi suggests to install the Eel module with "pip install" command -- https://pypi.org/project/Eel/)

I'll be very grateful to get your answer -)
P.S. I've checked cases and other spelling stuff=) I mean that module for python should be named **e**el but officially called **E**el (according to the naming on the pypi page https://pypi.org/project/Eel/)

Comment: Note that the default python/pip commands refer to the Python installation *used by and intended for the operating system*. You should not install anything to it directly. Create a virtual environment for isolation, or install a separate Python version (e.g. from python.org, via brew or anaconda) and use that to avoid messing with the system. In specific, never use sudo to install a python package unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be that you don't have pip installed.

I know most Mac's have pip and Python pre-installed, but it wouldn't hurt to try: `sudo easy_install pip`

If this doesn't seem to be the issue, you might be running the `pip install packageName` in the wrong directory.

You will need to access your scripts folder in python and run the `pip install packageName` command in there. Here is a resource which should help you reach that directory: https://datatofish.com/install-package-python-using-pip/